# LinearGradientBrush with InterpolateColors does not render correctly with small position values

Tags: c#, gdi+, lineargradientbrush

I was trying to make a ColorBlend editor with draggable position marker when I noticed that sometime, it does not seems to render correctly.

Using a LinearGradientBrush with an InterpolationColors fading from white to blue to white again and the middle position for blue is 0.02f. The middle gradient does not seems to be aligned with the position I provided.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var colorBlend = new ColorBlend {
        Colors = new[] { Color.White, Color.Blue, Color.White },
        Positions = new[] { 0f, 0.02f, 1f }
    };

    var rect = new RectangleF(10, 10, 500, 50);

    //colors in constructor are not supposed to matter, and InterpolationColors should override them
    using(var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Aqua, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal)
        {InterpolationColors = colorBlend})
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);

    for (var i = 0; i < colorBlend.Positions.Length; i++)
    {
        var x = rect.X + colorBlend.Positions[i] * rect.Width;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x, rect.Bottom, x, rect.Bottom + 20);
    }
}
```

[image: GradientTest]

The pure blue should be aligned with the middle marker, but the gradient continues a little after the marker before going back to white again.

When I use a position of 0.2f for the blue, the gradient seems fine.

Comment: Interesting! I can a) confirm that this is happening in my own gradientBuilder. And b) can offer a workaround: If you add another middle color (i.e. a 4th color) all seems to be well again, ie both the 2nd and the 3rd colors will render right up to the borders.. This also works if you place it to the borders and give it a border color.

Comment: The [sources](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Core/System/Windows/Media/LinearGradientBrush@cs/1/LinearGradientBrush@cs) are not very clear but it seems they construct the color by a unit circle going from end to end. As the numbers used are float it may run into trouble with precision. Cos(0.02) = 0.99999993907... (Just a wild guess)